# Access value of UITextField in different view on storyboard but having IBOutlet in one ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having four ViewController in storyboard and I am using only one ViewController.swift class. These views have UITextField to take input from user and these UITextFields have IBOutlet in ViewController.swift.

Now when i am am accessing the value of textfields in last viewcontroller using button which is also in last view controller so its accessble, but when i am trying to access values of first view controller, its not accessible.
I am getting error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value (lldb)

My four ViewController in story board are-

[image]

Comment: So there are 4 view controller scenes in the Storyboard and there is just the 1 ViewController.swift for all the scenes on the storyboard?

Comment: @Azzaknight yess it was but nw i have created four view controller for each and nw i want to pass data of first view controller to last view controller. Is it safe to use userdefaults for storing values.